# Discretize Graphics3D with Scale and Rotate?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, discretization

How can I discretize a [`Graphics3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) object that makes use of [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) and [`Rotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html)?  When I try [`DiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) I get an [`EmptyRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmptyRegion.html); the documentation warns of this, at least for `Scale`, under **Possible Issues**.

```
Graphics3D[Rotate[Scale[Ball[], {1, .7, .4}], 0.6, {0, 1, 2/3}]] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

> ```
> EmptyRegion[3]
> ```

I cannot use `Scale` and `Rotate` after discretizing.

```
Rotate[Scale[DiscretizeRegion@Ball[], {1, .7, .4}], 0.6, {0, 1, 2/3}]  (* fail *)
```

[`GeometricTransformation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) also fails.

```
GeometricTransformation[DiscretizeRegion @ Ball[], ScalingTransform[{1, .7, .4}]]
```

I am using version 10.1.

Comment: I think your last line is not correct. It should be like this: `DiscretizeRegion@
 TransformedRegion[Ball[], ScalingTransform[{1, .7, .4}]]`. `GeometricTransformation` is meant to be applied to graphics primitives. The equivalent for (mesh) regions would be `TransformedRegion`.

Comment: (As for the first one, I'd consider it a bug.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, `TransformedRegion` !! That's what I was forgetting.  LOL.  Thanks for working faster than my own brain. :D

Comment: I didn't test in 10.1 though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Szabolcs for jogging my failing memory; I couldn't remember [`TransformedRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html).

```
Fold[TransformedRegion, Ball[],
 {ScalingTransform[{1, .7, .4}], RotationTransform[0.6, {0, 1, 2/3}]}
]

% // DiscretizeRegion
```

> ```
> Ellipsoid[{0., 0., 0.}, {{0.764563, 0.119337, -0.334044}, {0.119337, 
>    0.537886, -0.0984315}, {-0.334044, -0.0984315, 0.347551}}]
> ```

[image]

Comment: You can also use `Composition` on transformation functions to obtain a single transformation.